# How can I copy-paste between emacs and other applications on mac?

Tags: macos, emacs

All of a sudden, I cannot anymore copy-paste text from Safari to Emacs. I don't think I changed anything relevant to my `.emacs` recently and I am pretty sure this was possible a few days ago. I am puzzled.

My version of emacs is 24.3 and my version of Mac OS X is 10.9.4.

Comment: Try Aquamacs - seems to have a bit better integration

Comment: Check that your key bindings are still ok in Emacs: what tell C-h k M-w and C-h k C-y? BTW are you still in the same Emacs session?

Comment: I'm using a developer build snapshot of Emacs Trunk on OSX 10.6.8 and I am able to copy and paste from Safari to Emacs.  One thing you may wish to try is running Emacs with no user settings to see if it works without them -- e.g., a blank / empty `.emacs` file.  If it works with an empty / blank `.emacs` file, then you will know that your user settings are to blame.  That is usually the first step that should be taken when things don't work as expected and when there are no error messages to help pinpoint the problem.  The only real advantage of Aquamacs is its use of the native spellchecker.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I should have definitely done that before posting! And I can confirm that I still cannot copy/paste with a blank `.emacs` file. What's puzzling is that it used to work!

Comment: @Seki M-w is bound to `kill-ring-save`and C-y to `yank` which is expected values I guess.

Comment: The Emacs builds from http://emacsformacosx.com/ are about as good as you can get without building yourself, and I prefer those builds over macports and homebrew.  I would recommend trying the last stable release from that web address, and if that doesn't work for you, try out a developer snapshot nightly build from that same website:  http://emacsformacosx.com/builds  If it doesn't work after that, well . . . you're probably out of luck with the exception of submitting an emacs-bug-report.

Comment: Latest release is the same one I currently use. Downloaded it to be sure it does not work either :-( Will try developers snapshots...

Comment: OK, I rebooted following an OS upgrade and it works again... Sigh... Thanks for your advices.